# JSON Parse, how to get a variable with an unknown first part?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Following is a JSON output from an API, I've had trouble trying to compare the "last_save" variables, and if a profile has a larger "last_save" value, set the "profile_id" as a variable. (Im fairly new to java script, sorry if I use incorrect terminology)

Here is the code:

```
function profileID(){
    console.log("Running profileID.")
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       rawJsonText = this.responseText;
       var parsedText = JSON.parse(rawJsonText);
       console.log(parsedText)
       console.log(playerUUID)
       lastPlayedIslandID = parsedText[0].last_save
       lastPlayedProfileName = parsedText.profile_id
       console.log(nameMC+"'s island ID : "+lastPlayedIslandID);
       console.log(nameMC+"'s island name : "+lastPlayedProfileName);
       slayerZombie();
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", slothpixelAPI+"skyblock/profiles/"+nameMC, true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

This is the JSON output from the API:

```
{
  "5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1": {
    "profile_id": "5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1",
    "cute_name": "Grapes",
    "first_join": 1578113432038,
    "last_save": 1582337480211,
    "collections_unlocked": 0,
    "members": [
      "4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93"
    ]
  },
  "4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93": {
    "profile_id": "4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93",
    "cute_name": "Coconut",
    "first_join": 1560932868602,
    "last_save": 1583315330184,
    "collections_unlocked": 59,
    "members": [
      "8d32864b3a364035922dd84d5247f483",
      "4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parsedText` is an object, not array, so number indexing isn't going to work. In fact objects [don't order their values as you'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). Use [`Object.keys(parsedText)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the names of the each value in the object, and iterate through them to find out what you need. There are other ways you can [iterate through an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) as well.

```
var parsedText = JSON.parse(rawJsonText);
var parsedKeys = Object.keys(parsedText);
var mostRecentProfile = "";

for(var i = 0; i < parsedKeys.length; i++) {
    if(mostRecentProfile) {
        if(parsedText[mostRecentProfile].last_save < parsedText[parsedKeys[i]].last_save) {
            // Current profile has more recent save
            mostRecentProfile = parsedKeys[i];
        }
    } else { // Set first profile as default
        mostRecentProfile = parsedKeys[i];
    }
}
console.log(parsedText[mostRecentProfile].last_save); // 1583315330184
```

A shorter way to do it if you're comfortable with one-liners is by getting only the values with [`Object.values(parsedText)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [sorting the objects by a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values) `last_save`, and selecting the first one.

```
var parsedText = JSON.parse(rawJsonText);
var mostRecentProfile = Object.values(parsedText).sort(function(a, b) {
    // Sort in descending order
    return b.last_save - a.last_save;
})[0].profile_id;
console.log(parsedText[mostRecentProfile].last_save); // 1583315330184
```

Answer (score 0):

I i have understood,i think you have only one object with 2 fields. I think your parsedText returns something like:

```
[{
"5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1": {"last_save": 1582337480211},
"4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93": {"last_save": 1583315330184}
}]
```

And parsedText[0] is like:

```
{
"5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1": {"last_save": 1582337480211},
"4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93": {"last_save": 1583315330184}
}
```

You could access to the childrens like:

```js
var text = '{"5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1": {"last_save": 1582337480211},"4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93": {"last_save": 1583315330184}}'
obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj)

console.log(obj["4878f8a455e84956b19d4873d837ab93"]["last_save"])
console.log(obj["5ab88f71d10747aabf643e666c9933b1"]["last_save"])
```